# having error in post request in four square

Tags: php, foursquare

lists/add?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&name=key while adding list in the four square, I am getting  this error.

> **Must provide parameter name****

but name parameter also i am sending, refer the above url.Please helping solve this issue.

Comment: how do you retrieve name, token, etc. give the code.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error in your code -- I can create a list using just the "name" param. See below:

```
Momo:~ ak$ curl --data name=foobar\&oauth_token=NZYZSJL2IOGPVMCTL1A3A30VVYAZK3PNWNZWJBTRC4MWPRMS\&v=20120411 https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/add
{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":1}}],"response":{"list":{"id":"4f859d91e4b0be4a120b2fa1","name":"foobar","description":"","type":"created","user":{"id":"606","firstName":"Akshay","lastName":"Patil","photo":"https:\/\/is0.4sqi.net\/userpix_thumbs\/YEOVWGYHWG5S05IP.jpg","gender":"male","homeCity":"New York, NY","bio":"Mayor of your heart","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/ak","relationship":"self"},"editable":true,"public":true,"collaborative":false,"url":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/ak\/list\/foobar","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/ak\/list\/foobar","createdAt":1334156689,"updatedAt":1334156689,"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"like":false,"comments":{"count":0,"items":[]},"doneCount":0,"visitedCount":0,"venueCount":0,"categories":{"count":0,"items":[]},"following":false,"followers":{"count":0},"collaborators":{"count":0,"items":[]},"listItems":{"count":0,"items":[]}}}}Momo:~ ak$
```